# Exim4 slow connection and transaction time

Tags: debian, smtp, exim

I've setup my email server and have run some tests from mxtoolbox.com Everything is working properly but the only issue I have is a slow connection and transaction time.

[image]

What could this be caused by as I've tried to troubleshoot but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many things could result in delays. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with mxtoolbox.com. I assume you have access to a command line?

A misconfigured Exim feature might be trying to verify something about the sender/message and exim processes the message only after the feature times out. Here are some of the things I've run into:

1. Name resolution issues. Solution: update "resolv.conf" with working DNS servers (try 8.8.8.8)
2. ipv6 issues. Solution: disable ipv6
3. Virus/Spam checking: Try disabling it
4. RFC1413 issues: try `rfc1413_query_timeout = 2s` or `rfc1413_query_timeout = 0` which turns off the check entirely

You could also try running `exim -v` or `exim -d` and watch the debugging output to view what exim is doing when it hangs.  This [article](https://github.com/Exim/exim/wiki/TestingExim) might help.

Good luck

Comment: The rfc1413 setting did improve the  times.